# Russell's Principia Mathematica status

Tags: logic, soft-question, foundations, research

I have recently read the excellent graphic novel "Logicomix" and I was wondering how Russell's work is considered in the modern mathematical community. I know that Wittgenstein and, much more formally Gödel, have dealt hard blows to the Principia (and every other formal systems for what matters) but does it continue to have some value as the logical foundation of mathematics? Is it advisable to read it or is it dated and is it better to focus on more optimized alternatives?  And in this case what are the alternatives? Modern set theory?

Comment: I don't think anyone reads it or refers to it anymore other than for historical purpose.

Comment: It is incredibly dated, and I would not recommend reading it (unless you're interested in its historical value). Logic has advanced considerably(!) since PM, and there are many issues with PM which are avoided in systems which are also much easier to use. The [Stanford Encyclopedia article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) on the topic positively emphasizes the significance of PM, but also (at the beginning) summarizes some criticisms of PM; I think the cited articles by Godel and Urquhardt are particularly relevant.

Comment: Related : [What did Whitehead and Russell's Principia Mathematica achieve ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597819/what-did-whitehead-and-russells-principia-mathematica-achieve)

Comment: No "hard blows" from Wittgenstein at all... Regarding Gödel, the fundamental G's discoveries were made possible exactly by *Principia* detailed development of Mathematical logic and foundations.