# Principia Mathematica and Axioms

Tags: logic, book-recommendation, axioms, philosophy

I have been trying to understand how mathematicians achieve the truth through axiomatic systems. Surely, if one searches a bit more, it will get to know how axiomatic systems work, generally. After that, I got to know, for example, why there are geometries, instead of one (the Euclidian) taught at school; Quantum Mechanics vs. Newton's ... and so on.... However, I really would like to know how can axiomatic systems be created. Then, I searched a bit more and got Principia Mathematica (PM), Whitehead & Russell, to read, but comments on the book disappointeded me.

So the questions are:

1) Which book should I read so as to understand how axiomatic systems work? Also, one that enables me creating my own, for example.

2) Is there a more complete book than Principia Mathematica? Recently, I read Gödel's theorem and understood the basic concept: there is no axiomatic system that is FULLY COMPLETE. But it can have a more complete book than PM.

Comment: Find an existing axiom system and change one or more of the axioms. Now you have your own axiom system. Does this answer part of your question 1?

Comment: Euclid's *Elements* is still a good start. Then read Hilbert's modern (and revised) version of Euclid's system.

Comment: See, at "archive.org" :  Richardson,  Fundamentals Of Mathematics , ch17 , §157 " A miniature geometry" . Also, May , Modern Mathematics ( final chapter). Also, Papineau , Philosophical Devices.

Comment: Regarding PM, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597819/what-did-whitehead-and-russells-principia-mathematica-achieve).

Comment: Also, Wilder, Introduction To The Foundations Of Mathematics. ( at archive.org).

Comment: Maybe probability theory is a good example of an axiomatic system relying on a limited set of axioms. There is a MIT video course on this topic .

Comment: One point to be emphasized is that in an axiomatic system, the nature of the objects is not explained, that is, there are no explicit defnitions. ( For example , in set theory, the term " set" is not defined. A set is supposed to be anything that satisfies the axioms.) This feature is called " formalization" and dates back from the 19th century.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, surely I am going to read the articles, book, posts etc mentioned by you. By the way, @RayLittleRock, would "set" be a primitive object then?

Comment: Well, @Somos, yes. However, the main thing would be: how should I conceive the new one. As far as I have read, it seems I can state whatever I want, but I don't think it is just this....

Comment: @Mr. N - I think that " set" is actually what one calls a " primitive term".( In axiomatic set theory).

Comment: As to the way an axiomatic system " works " and the underlying mechanisms, the importance of the Deduction Theorem can be pointed out: <https://www3.nd.edu/~cfranks/dt.pdf>

Answer (score 2):

You come up with your own axioms, and see where they lead.  I have never created my own set of axioms, but historically, mathematicians have taken existing axiomatic systems and tried changing one (or more) of the axioms, and seeing if they can build a self-consistent system.  The most famous example of this is Riemann replacing the parallel postulate from geometry, leading to Riemannian geometry.  Other examples lead to broader conceptions of numbers.

You might appreciate:  ***Defending the Axioms: On the Philosophical Foundations of Set Theory*** by Penelope Maddy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, axioms are conceived of by thinking about what would be *useful* given a set of concepts, and which seem obviously true, but which also seem to not be falsifiable.

However, we need to be careful when defining axioms, as some have historically been shown to produce contradictions, as was the case with Russell's Paradox. One proposed axiom for set theory was that for any property of a mathematical object, there exists a set of all objects with that property. Bertrand Russell showed you can derive a contradiction from that proposed axiom by considering the set of all sets S with the property that S is not a member of itself (and I'll leave it up to you to reason out why or read into it).

I unfortunately don't have much in the way of books, but I can definitely recommend **Axiomatic Set Theory** by Patrick Suppes, or possibly even **Naive Set Theory** by Paul R. Halmos. The former is more in-depth, but the latter definitely shows you that you can derive quite a bit from just a few axioms and some definitions.